# Best Practice for Accessing SharePoint List Item through Object Model

Tags: sharepoint

I would like to know the best Practice that you guys follow when it comes to access the SharePoint List Items / Doc Lib using Object Model. To start let me share few things I have found.

1. Limit the number of Items Per container to 2K items.
2. Use ProcessWebData method of SPWeb to do Update/Insert of Large items

Answer (score 1):

To completely answer your question would require a full blog post. There are several of these out there on the IntraWebs already.

Here are a few of the major points:

- Avoid iterating though the entire list unless you need to see every item
- If you do iterate through the list, use a foreach loop instead of a for loop
- In all other cases use an SPQuery or an SPSiteData query
- Access columns by the internal name or the field ID

Comment: One example is http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/Accessing+List+Items+using+SPList+using+the+object+model but it's incomplete regarding performance.

Answer (score 0):

You should also take a look at [Common Coding Issues When Using the SharePoint Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/library/bb687949.aspx) as it has some examples on how to avoid serious performance problems.